# Matlab extend a function on scalar to a function on matrix

Tags: matlab, function, matrix, scalar

In [Matlab page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) array provided a simple method to extend a scalar function $func$ to vector and matrix(and high dimensional tensor), i.e.

```
B = arrayfun(func,A)
```

However, when I attempted to do the same, it returned an error

```
function [output_matrix]=func(y1_matrix)
    output_matrix = arrayfun( func_elementwise  ,y1_matrix);

    function [output_x]=func_elementwise(x1)
    % a scalar function
    ...(Arguments that had been verified worked)
    end

end
```

when I attempted to run the function, it returned

```
Not enough input arguments.
Error in func/func_elementwise 
        x1=mod(x1,2*pi)-pi;

Error in func
output_matrix = arrayfun( func_elementwise  ,y1_matrix);
```

Could you tell me what went wrong? why arrayfun did not work for func_elementwise? (the attempted inputs for func were scalar and 1*N matrix, both did not work. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code,

```
arrayfun(func_elementwise,y1_matrix)
```

you call the function `func_elementwise` without arguments:

```
func_elementwise
```

is the same as

```
func_elementwise()
```

You need to pass a function handle to `arrayfun`, like so:

```
arrayfun(@func_elementwise,y1_matrix)
```

Comment: @ShoutOutAndCalculate Note that [`arrayfun`'s documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html#d120e45338) says that its first input should be the "function to apply to the elements of the input arrays, _specified as a function handle_"

Answer (score 1):

In that case you need to pass func_elementwise as a function handle to arrayfunc:

```
arrayfun(@func_elementwise, y1_matrix)
```

Further details in Matlab Help:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/226399-arrayfun-with-a-function-that-takes-multiple-inputs

Comment: Sorry, I meant function handle. Like Cris Luengo said. You need to pass the function as a function handle. Sorry by don't giving a better explanation. That's why I included the link to answer in Mathworks.